# Data from an arduino to be transferred to COSM through wireless internet

Tags: arduino, wireless

I am trying to collect data from sensors through an arduino and send it over to the COSM server. My main problem is that the arduino will be in an environment where it will be impossible for me to provide an internet router and thus must find a way in which i can send the data to the internet through a wireless connection.

I would appreciate it if you could give me an answer that does not involve using a wifi shield coupled with data connection through a cell phone as i want it to run even in the absence of cell phone data packets.

Comment: What distance do you need to cover, when, how much data, what is an acceptable latency?

Comment: Just so I understand: You cannot use wired ethernet, no WiFi, no cellphone, unspecified range... Hmm.

Comment: okay i am trying to collect diagnostic data from a car through some sensors i plan to install in it. Accounting for the scenario in which the car gets stolen i found it relevant to add the above constraints . And i know that an arduino is not the best way to go.just building a prototype :)

Comment: If I see a car wired up to an Arduino, I don't even want to think about stealing it ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints specified in the question, here are a couple of data communication options:

1. **Zigbee** module connected to the Arduino, in End Device mode, another Zigbee module in Coordinator mode on a PC connected to the wired network: 802.15.4 protocol, 250 Kbps speed (2.4 GHz modules), 10 to 50 meters range, 75 meters if you are lucky
2. **Bluetooth** module or shield on Arduino, Bleutooth on a PC connected to the wired network: 802.15.1 protocol, 1 MBPS (non EDR) speed, 10 meters range

Other options include IrDA, which has much greater data rates, but range of a couple of meters - Good for an RFI-heavy environment where the RF solutions fail. Then there are RF data modules such as the nrf24l01+ wireless transceiver that can be considered as well.

Without desired cost, data rate and range constraints, a more specific answer may be difficult to put together.

<sub>I am refraining from suggesting smoke signals, Ouija boards, or a graduate student tasked with transcribing data into a data entry screen.</sub>

Comment: If i were to use a wifi shield could i connect to the internet without the help of a cell phone?

Comment: @VineetKaushik WiFi shield --> (WiFi Access Point -->) WiFi router --> DSL/ADSL/other broadband/leased line --> Internet Service Provider --> COSM. Something in the network needs to be connected through an ISP to the Internet, for your device to be connected to the Internet.